# First time F1 visa went wrong and rejected. Help me rectify for 2nd time!

Tags: usa, student-visa, refusal, interview

Below is my conversation with the Visa Officer (VO). I tried to recreate the conversation as best as I could remember. I have another appointment for the visa interview in a week. Please help me improve any aspect that I might have done wrong. Thanks a lot!

> Me: Hello, Good Morning?
>   VO: Good Morning, pass the i20 and Passport please!
>   Me: Here you go.
>   VO: Georgia Institute of Technology! Personal Funds! So, how are you going to manage this much money?
>   Me: I have 134,000 dollars in my accounts. Moreover, my father can provide any further expenses that might occur.
>   VO: In which account?
>   Me: In multiple accounts.
>   VO: How did you get this much money?
>   Me: Well most of the money is from my mother's savings, that I got after she passed away from cancer 7 years ago, as I am the only child.
>   VO: How did your mother get this money? What did she do?
>   Me: Well most of the money is from mother's saving….
>   VO: Yeah, I know, but how did she get it?
>   Me: Well my mother used to run a private medical school, alongside my father, who is a government doctor and some of his colleagues. There, primary health care was taught to students who enrolled in the program…
>   VO: Typing for a while…..
>   Me: Waiting
>   VO: Typing…..
>   Me: Should I show you my account statements?
>   VO: uhmm.. No need.
>   Me: Okay...
>   VO: Typing…..
>   Me: *waiting*
>   Me: Can I add something?
>   VO: Go ahead.
>   Me: My father works as a government doctor. Presently he is posted as Assistant Director, for the Ministry of Health, Government of Bangladesh. He also has a private practice.
>   VO: Typing…
>   VO: Sir, … how did you get here today?
>   Me: By car.
>   VO: Is that your car? Do you own that car?
>   Me: No, I rented that car.
>   VO: Oh! You rented that car! Okay.
>   Me: *dumbfounded*
>   VO: *Typing for a while again. Hands me the white leaflet.*  Sorry Sir, you do not qualify for the visa you have applied for. Have a good day!
>   Me: Thank you sir.

Comment: Why do people think this question is unclear? Obviously he's asking (1) why did the officer decide he's not eligible for this visa, and (2) what did he say that led the officer to this decision?

Answer (score 1):

Others may give other suggestions, and your US university should give you advice as well, but I'll focus on your last line *"Thank you sir."*  This is understood as gracious acceptance of the officer's decision, but gracious acceptance won't help you much in this or any American legal matters.  You will get better results by being **polite but assertive**.

To be polite but assertive, you need to prepare ahead of time by learning the rules that the officer is required to follow.  For example, according to the [US State Department page on visa denials](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-denials.html):

> If denied a visa, in most cases the applicant is notified of the section of law which applies. Visa applicants are also advised by the consular officer if they may apply for a waiver of their ineligibility.

Prepared with this and further understanding of the US visa process, at that point you might say something like **"Could you tell me the reason?"** or even more boldly "I believe I'm well qualified, do I misunderstand?"  Even if the officer still denies the visa, at least you will get some clarification about what went wrong.

Comment: They have handed me a leaflet citing the 214b Law, which says that I am a potential immigrant. There's a range of reason cited under that law. Thing is, all F1 visa denied are handed the 214b leaflet. So, I am not entirely sure about the definite reasons. My guess is because I am having to pay such a large amount for my first year (66k USD)

Comment: Without knowing more, I don't understand why you rented a car to go to your visa interview. My point isn't about the car. My point is that if the officer doesn't clearly understand your story (or any subplot of it) and your ties to your home country, the officer is required by US law to assume you're trying to immigrate to the US, making you ineligible for a nonimmigrant visa like F-1. So you'll want to be assertive in providing answers that make your overall situation clear to the officer.